# Wtforms: adding dynamic fields with multiple inheritance

Tags: python, forms, wtforms

I know I can create dynamic fields like this: http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.1/specific_problems.html#dynamic-form-composition

But the above solution is unwieldy in my case, and requires a special API which I would like to avoid. I am wondering if there is a way to get this working with multiple inheritance?  I tried the following and it won't work and I don't know why, I figured that WTForms should bind the forms properly given how the class structure is working:

```
>>> class Base(Form):
...     def __init__(self, **kwargs):
...         setattr(self, 'dynamic_boolean', fields.BooleanField('label'))
...         super(Base, self).__init__(**kwargs)
... 
>>> class Inherit(Base):
...     other_boolean = fields.BooleanField('label')
... 
>>> 
>>> form = Inherit()
>>> form.__dict__
{'dynamic_boolean': <UnboundField(BooleanField, ('label',), {})>, 'other_boolean': <wtforms.fields.core.BooleanField object at 0x8a8510c>, '_fields': {'other_boolean': <wtforms.fields.core.BooleanField object at 0x8a8510c>}, '_prefix': '', '_errors': None}
```

As you can see the dynamic_boolean is unbound. How can I set this up so that the dynamic_boolean field is bound properly?

Comment: Your topic doesn't seem to match your question. WTForms *does* support multiple inheritance, but that's unrelated to what you're trying to do, which is something akin to dynamic composition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

WTForms uses [a metaclass](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/2.0/wtforms/form.py#L167) to handle binding at instantiation time. This metaclass does its work *before* `Form.__init__` is called, thus making it not possible for something in `__init__` to create a field that's bound.

The way WTForms is designed is done so as to reduce the amount of work to be done in searching for and finding field classes to only happen the first time a form is instantiated, speeding up your application after the initial request.

---

**Alternately** If you're willing to put in the legwork, it is possible to design something similar to Form that supports this behavior, based on [BaseForm](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/forms.html#low-level-api) and using your own metaclass. Be warned, BaseForm is not the same thing as Form, it's purely a low-level way designed for authors of complementary libraries to get access to build similar tools.

Comment: Adding a classmethod that returns a new form works as well. Maybe points someone in the right direction.

Comment: Did anyone put in the legwork and would like to share?