# Can I add field in __init__ wtforms

Tags: python, wtforms, flask-wtforms

for some reason I need to declare a field inside the `__init__()` so I can make arbitrary type of `FormField`.

Take for example in `form.py`:

```
class PurchaseForm(Form):
    item_class = ItemForm
    transaction_items = FieldList(FormField(item_class),
                                  label='items',
                                  min_entries=1)

    def __init__(self, item_class, *args, **kwargs):
       super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.item_class = item_class
       self.transaction_items = FieldList(FormField(self.item_class),
                                           label='items',
                                           min_entries=1)
```

If I do it like that, the `transaction_items` field is not replaced by the `__init__()`, can I do something to override it? or do something like `setattr` for this specific instance?

---

Edit: Here is how I specify the constructor

```
import form

@app.route('/add/purchase-transaction', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_purchase_transaction():
    form = forms.PurchaseForm(form.ItemForm)

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # do something

    return render_template('add-purchase-transaction.html', form=form)
```

So my goal is to make a `PurchaseForm` which has a `FieldList` containing `ItemForm` form class, and in the future I can swap `ItemForm` to different class, for example to `PurchaseItemForm`

Comment: You should re-read the part where you explain what happens when you remove the class attribute. Currently it does not make sense.

Comment: Yeah thanks, have changed it

Comment: Can you specify how you're initializing the instance and also where `transaction_label` and `self.transaction_label` are defined?

Comment: Edited the answer, it is in there, how I specify the instance constructor. About `transaction_label` it is similar to how `transaction_items` behaves, for now I just removed it to avoid duplicates

Comment: Wilfo is absolutely right, it is because Form being a metaclass. I joined stackoverflow just now to ask andiwinta if they could post their new PurchaseFOrm(BaseForm). I have the same problem when trying to use the super().__init__(), and trying to extend the Form class. Much Appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To start with, I think your `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)` is not valid and should be `super(PurchaseForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)` - we're you able to run your code like that?

Also, how can you tell it's not working - looking into a created form from this code - it looks ok:

```
class ItemForm(Form):
    openid = StringField('openid', validators=[])
    remember_me = BooleanField('remember_me', default=False)

class PurchaseForm(Form):
    item_class = ItemForm
    transaction_items = None

    def __init__(self, item_class, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PurchaseForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.item_class = item_class
        self.transaction_items = FieldList(FormField(self.item_class),
                                           label='items',
                                           min_entries=1)
```

Comment: I think `super().__init__()` is valid for Python 3. I followed your example, but it is still the same, it is compiled okay but jinja2 throws error (sorry just mention it now). So the error from jinja2 is `TypeError: 'UnboundField' object is not iterable` and it is from `{% for item in form.transaction_items  %}`

Comment: look at the reply to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23594448/wtforms-adding-dynamic-fields-with-multiple-inheritance) - it looks like what you're trying to do is not a good practice from the point of view of `WTForms`

Comment: ahh, i see so that how it works. I'll just split it for each type of form then. Thanks!