# WTForms how to render RadioField as StringField

Tags: python, flask-wtforms, wtforms

Since it's pretty hard to [dynamically change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23594448/wtforms-adding-dynamic-fields-with-multiple-inheritance) a WTForm, I'm trying to render a `FieldList` of `RadioFields` as if it were a `FieldList` of `StringFields`. My form looks something like this:

```
class SingleForm(FlaskForm):

    radio = RadioField()


class EntireForm(FlaskForm):

    # fieldlist of singleforms
    field_forms = FieldList(FormField(SingleForm))
```

and I'm currently rendering my code like so (normal radio buttons)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        {% for single_form in form.field_forms %}
            <td>
                {{ single_form.form.radio(required='required') }}
            </td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
</table>
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32407564/dynamically-change-wtforms-field-type-between-selectfield-and-hiddenfield), I've tried to change the widget type of my form in my `routes.py` before rendering like so:

```
# this actually adds some SingleForm RadioFields to the FieldList...
some_amount_of_fields = 5
for idx in range(some_amount_of_fields):
    form.field_forms.append_entry({})

# now change their widget type...
for single_form in form.field_forms:
    single_form.form.widget = HiddenInput()
```

But this just didn't render at all. Any advice on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone stumbling upon this later, I solved this purely in HTML using Jinja:

```
<form>
    {% for single_form in form.field_form %}
        <input type="text" id="{{ single_form.form.radio.label.field_id }}" name="{{single_form.form.radio.name }}" required='required')>
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

This automatically fills the original form, so no need to insert manually afterwards.